# Why the contents of queue are shown when I use "for loop" but not when I use "while loop"?

Tags: c++, stl, queue

I want to display the contents of a queue in C++, so I decided to copy the queue into a temporary one and then display the elements of the new queue repetitive pop operations. But the following code shows output only when I use the `for` loop.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    queue<int> Q;
    queue<int> dump = Q;

    Q.push(1);
    Q.push(2);
    Q.push(3);
    Q.push(4);

    // for (dump = Q; !dump.empty(); dump.pop())   //THIS WORKS
    //     cout << dump.front() << '\n';

    while(!dump.empty())              //THIS DOES NOT
    { 
        cout << dump.front() << '\n';
        dump.pop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

These two lines of code:

```cpp
    queue<int> Q;
    queue<int> dump = Q;
```

Declare `Q` and `dump` to be `queue` objects. `Q` is default initialized to an *empty* queue and `dump` is initialized to be a copy of (the empty) `Q`.

The following four lines:

```cpp
    Q.push(1);
    Q.push(2);
    Q.push(3);
    Q.push(4);
```

Push the four numbers, `1`, `2`, `3` and `4` into the `Q` object **but do not change** the `dump` object.

In your `for` loop, the "initial" statement, `dump = Q;` copies the `Q` object (now adjusted after the 4 pushes) into `dump` (overwriting the existing empty object), so the loop prints out the four entries.  However, the `while` loop doesn't have that initial statement, so the `dump` object remains as it was in the original assignment (initialization) - which is empty!

To fix this you can do one of two things.

1. Move the declaration/definition of `dump` (along with its initialization) to *after* the four `Q.push()` calls. This will then copy the 'filled' `Q` object to `dump`.
2. You can declare `dump` as a ***reference*** to a `queue`. Then, whenever you 'assign' another `queue` object to it (like, say, in: `dump = Q`), any changes you make to `Q` will be reflected in `dump` (as it *refers* to the original object).

To use the reference method, use the following syntax (this is the *only* change you need to make to your code):

```cpp
    queue<int>& dump = Q;
```

The added `&` character is what declares `dump` as a reference. (This works, in many ways, like a pointer, but you don't need the explicit `*` to deference it, as you would with a pointer [[More info from Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)).)

**But please note**: As pointed out by [Alexander Zhang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9254539/alexander-zhang), if you use this second (reference) method, then ***all*** changes you then make to `dump` will ***also*** be made to `Q` (because `dump` still *refers* to `Q`); so the `dump.pop();` line in the loop(s) will - in effect - be popping values from `Q` (and thus `Q` will be emptied). If you don't want this, then you should use the first method above (moving the location of the `queue<int> dump = Q;` line).

Comment: If you make `dump` a reference you will empty the original queue when printing the contents.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang I can incorporate your comment into my answer, if you're happy with that?

Comment: Yeah, that would be nice.